# Post Infopath Form remotely using REST SharePoint 2013

Tags: development, infopath, rest, visual-studio-2015

I am  a C#/DBA/Web developer using VS 2015 and new to Infopath/SharePoint so no bashing please.  Got thrown into this project and have been banging head against wall for week trying to resolve this.
Requirements are:
1. POST Infopath form using C# from one server to SharePoint server - form will be editable in SharePoint list (like it currently is).

Here is what I have attempted so far:

1. Using REST via httpwebrequest in this article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx
   This allows me to GET but not to POST data.  When attempting to post I get the dreaded 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.'
2. Using Lists.asmx web service I get the dreaded 'List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.' when trying to post xml to the list using CAML.
3. Using CopySoapClient it uploads the xml doc but it is not editable like the info path form.
4. I know this is a no-no but I had to try just to see if it was possible - inserting directly into database adds list item but that is not editable like info path form (and not supported before I get the lecture I have seen on every forum).

Is this possible?  Should I create a ashx handler page on site to SP server for remote server to post directly onto SP server so I can utilize the Sharepoint.dll itself?  Should I get SP Admin to create custom Infopath form that reads/writes into separate SQL DB but populates a SP List?

PS-I can clean up and provide code samples if needed - as stated before using REST GET is working fine and I am getting all list items and related xml.  POST gives me error.